# Piping two never ending python process

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, pipe

So I have 2 python programs
`p1.py`

```py
import datetime
import time

#while(1): ---> stuck
for i in range(5):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(2)
```

and
`p2.py`

```py
import time
while(1):
    print('received: ', input())
```

Now I am `piping` the output of `p1.py` to `p2.py` with

```py
python p1.py | python p2.py
```

This bash command should start 2 independent processes in parallel, but it seems it hangs until `p1.py` finishes, then the `p2.py` stats getting the input. And if I change the `for in` with infinite `while(1)` the program just freezes.

My expectation was that process `p1` will emit every 2 seconds and process `p2` will consume it and I will get output in terminal emulator at every 2 second, where is my understaing wrong regarding pipe?

Comment: Try with `python -u` to switch off buffering.

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you. `python -u p1.py | python p2.py`